# Is there a software to find a soundtrack inside another one?

Tags: software

For example, I have a small piece of a song, about 20 sec and there is a soundtrack of 4 hours where this 20 sec somewhere definitely is. So is there a software where i can upload my little piece and a big one, press a button and it will give me a time, where in the big one the small one starts?

Comment: If I were you, given the lack of available existing software, I would rework this question to ask how to develop such a process, and then submit it to a more computer science oriented exchange. Think like this: automatically breaking the file into 20 second chucks and then somehow comparing the pattern of those chunks to that of your 20 second sample and returning matches above a certain similarity threshold.

Comment: I already stated this to him also Doritostyle? You 'corrected' me then down voted me only to repeat what I already said! Twice!

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of any that can do this. Its quite a specific task that not many people would ever use  ...the only remotely similar use would be youtube who look at uploads and scan to see if there is any copyright music in uploads but not something that we can leverage from

Comment: This is what I've said already. Despite being down voted several times. In the context of commercially available software it's a function that isn't provided. It's technically possible but for the sake of the OP and keeping it relevant I can't see how one would do it. Why it's so hard to understand!

Answer (score -3):

No, there isn't. The only way current software can do this is if you mark where it is so it can recall it. But then if you knew where it was you wouldnt need software to do it. Think about it though, how can you expect any software to know what part of a 4 hour long file YOU want?

Comment: well, considering everything inside computer is bytes, the program need to find exact same sequence of bytes from small part inside another one, the bigger. I think it is possible...

Comment: I can assure you it isn't.

Comment: Technically it could be possible, as in forensic audiologists for the FBI could probably do it. But in the context of the creative industries it isn't something that is featured in audio DAWs. It's not a function most people need. Modern DAWs are incredibly complex in terms of programming and bugs with out adding useless features, developers try to give users features most people need. And most DAWs work invariably the same way. Your not going to find any software (certainly of all the popular DAWs) that will do some inconspicuous operation for your specific problem.

Comment: Your best option is to drop both files in to a DAW and scroll through until you find an obvious visual match in waveform. Not as difficult as it sounds just time consuming.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. It could be faster, than listening through 4 hours.

Comment: Check out digital signal processing - autocorrelation. It's certainly possible.

Comment: @Melloj it's very dangerous to speak authoritatively about things you aren't intimately familiar with. This is certainly possible for the exact reason Shouchy mentions and as evidenced by a similar system in use on Youtube as mentioned in this answer: http://sound.stackexchange.com/a/40648/9881

Comment: However, It's definitely a difficult prospect for which (to my knowledge) no commercially available software exists, and that makes this more of a computer science question IMO.

Comment: Which is why my point stands. I already stated it's technically possible. In the context of the OP who clearly does not have the inclination to do it my advice was simply no.